# Installed Python 3, now my Anaconda environment is messed up

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

I apologize in advance for my poor vocabulary - I do not know much about environments, paths, and things of the sort. I am on macOS Catalina.

I created a program using Spyder from Anaconda. My program uses packages like pandas and numpy which are built into Anaconda. I used to be able to run the program in Terminal with the command: `$ python3 app.py`.

However, I recently downloaded Python 3.9.1 from https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/. Ever since then, I have been unable to run the program in Terminal because of missing package errors like

```
import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I went to my applications folder, right clicked on Python 3.9.1, and clicked Move To Trash. This did not solve my problem. I reinstalled Anaconda (I did not uninstall it - just simply installed again), but that also did not solve my problem. I am able to run the program in Spyder (from Anaconda), but I wish to run it in Terminal again.

I believe the solution is simple, but I am not sure what to do. I have tried searching and reading but I am not familiar with the terminology. I think I just need to reset the environment, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is used for creating closed enviorments, so you don't need to thrash your computer with global packages.
Imagine you have 2 different projects. Project A works only on python 3.2 and Project B works on 3.8.

That's where anaconda comes in.[Managing enviorments with conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

```
conda create -n PROJECTA python=3.2
conda create -n PROJECTB python=3.8
```

Now activate env you wish to work with. For macOS

```
source activate PROJECTA
```

Now you should see (PROJECTA) instead of (base)
Now inside this PROJECTA you can install modules you require like

```
pip install numpy
```

and when executing .py file
move to dir with your app.py file and

```
python3 app.py
```

this will be opened in conda enviorment you created and activated, using modules you installed in this env.

You can still edit py file and execute it through shell, but it will throw errors if you try to run it from IDE without linking project to respected conda enviorment.

If you are using PyCharm [Configure a Conda vir env in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html)

Comment: I am trying to understand. I think installing Python 3.9.1 made changes to (base) and I am wondering how do I revert those changes? I used to be able to run my program in terminal without activating an environment. I wish to do the same.

Comment: Did you install numpy after installing Python 3.9.1? I guess I'm trying to say with my anwser, that in the future, to avoid this, you should use envs.

Answer (score 0):

You must create separate environments for every projects or it will get messed up.

> conda create -n name_of_environment python=3.6

You must not delete the python folder into trash rather uninstall it Python 3.9.1 and remove its path from the directory.

In short if you run python from terminal and it is not supporting your Installed anaconda packages . You should use anaconda prompt instead of CMD.

Because your anaconda is not added to path rather then it picks up the python 3.9 you have installed from  Python 3.9.1 from https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/. ( This is the python with separate environment then anaconda so it wont detect anaconda packages ).

When you run the cmd and enter python it runs the python that you downloaded and installed rather then Anaconda
[image: Adding path in windows]

At the time of installing anaconda it gives option to add conda variables to path you can select those at installing stage / or add manually